# difficulties in differentiate between \q{} and \cite{} using regex

Tags: r, regex

I have troubles replacing similar but different expression using regex.

For instance, I have the following text

```
\q{(ir)rational} and \cite{feldman_cbs_2016}
```

that needs to be

```
"(ir)rational" and [@feldman_cbs_2016]
```

I am using the following r code

```
x <- (gsub('\\\\q\\{|\\}','"',"\\q{(ir)rational} and  \\cite{feldman_cbs_2016}",fixed=F))


x <- gsub('\\\\cite\\{','[@',x,fixed=F)
```

but it yields

```
[1] "\"(ir)rational\" and  [@feldman_cbs_2016\""
```

The first part is correct but not the end of the second one that should not have been replaced with a quotation mark. Basically, I need to replace the quotation mark only when there is \q{} and not for every curly bracket such as \cite{}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, judging by the code sampe, you have ``\q{(ir)rational} and  \cite{feldman_cbs_2016}`` string, with single backslashes.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i have

Comment: Try `gsub('\\\\cite\\{([^{}]+)}','[@\\1]', gsub('\\\\q\\{([^{}]+)}','"\\1"',a))`

Comment: Is there any other cases? Like nested braces?